# UINavigationController -> Partial Curl Segue -> Another Segue?

Tags: ios, segue

I have a main UINavigationController that performs a Partial Curl segue to show a set of on/off switches. Some of the on/off switches must ensure a configuration variable exists (like foursquare). If those configurations do not exist, then I want to push another authentication Segue (again, foursquare). Now, If I do the following from the ViewController on the Partial Curl segue

```
FoursquareAuthViewController *controller = [[FoursquareAuthViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

the FoursquareAuthViewController will be behind the Partial Curl. What is the best way of having this work properly - ie. having the FoursquareAuthViewController take up the full screen - preferably from a modal segue?

I was thinking about passing the source controller as the delegate to the Partial Curl controller, then when the switch is flipped, checking if the configuration exists. If it does not, trigger the delegate to push the FoursquareAuthViewController. It just seems kind of goofy to do that way...

Update:

Attempting either of the following doesnt actually do anything.

```
FoursquareAuthViewController *controller = [[FoursquareAuthViewController alloc] init];
[[[self presentingViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:true];


FoursquareAuthViewController *controller = [[FoursquareAuthViewController alloc] init];
[[self presentingViewController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it'd help to present your Foursquare login view controller from the source view controller rather than from the switches view controller. But if it does, you don't need the "goofy" situation of passing view controllers around that you describe: from the switches view controller, you can reference `self.presentingViewController` to get the source view controller.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I am looking for. But, unfortunately its not actually doing anything. See update above.